# Pylint import could not be resolved

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I develop on WSL ubuntu with vscode and python3.10.
I installed tweepy but vscode returns this error, and this does not allow suggestions by pressing CTRL+BACKSPACE.
The error is as follows:
[image]

The interpreter is already set to python3.10, and in setting.json I have this:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true
}
```

This problem occurs every time, and I really don't know how to solve it, would you have any ideas about this? Even trying to change python version there is no change.

These are the python-related extensions installed:
Python, Pylance, IntelliCode

If I try to run the code (with python3.10) I get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy', this problem, however, does not occur in python3.7

Comment: How did you install Python 3.7 and Python 3.10? You said in your question you changed the Python version. How did you do that?

Comment: I installed python like this: "sudo apt install python3.10"

Comment: Please add all relevant details to your question. What have you done before to get to that system, what have you tried to solve the problem, and what's the current status?

Answer (score 1):

Both Pylance and Python say that tweepy isn't installed. That means it's almost certainly not installed in the environment you're using.

It sounds like there are multiple Python installations or virtual environments on your machine. My guess is that the one with Python 3.7 has tweepy and the one with Python 3.10 does not. To find out more, we'd need to know how you installed Python and its different versions. There are many ways to do that and they have little in common.

However, that's probably not necessary: just switch to the Python 3.10 environment and install tweepy the same way you did before, e.g. with `pip install tweepy` if you usually use pip for installing modules from PyPI.

Comment: Exactly, I think this is the problem, I have several versions of python. But how do I install this library for python3.10? I also tried giving pip3.10 install tweepy but it didn't solve it.

Comment: I don't know because I know too little about your system. Typically you'd change environments with `venv` or `conda`. Does one of these ring a bell? All you have to do is change the environment before you run `pip`.

Comment: I do not have conda installed. I have this on my wsl: /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.7
/usr/bin/python3.8

Comment: I see. I think this is a good explanation of how to switch versions with that setup: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

Comment: I think the problem is related to vscode, because I followed the guide but the problem was not solved. Using python3.10 on vscode, pylance doesn't see tweepy and other libraries that install from the outside only the internal ones (e.g. os, sys etc)

Comment: So what works now and what doesn't? What's the output of `import sys` `sys.version`? What happens when you run `pip install tweepy` after switching to the desired version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246314/discussion-between-joooeey-and-difettoso).